# Is it ok to use char* like a function type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I read about char*, that it should be used and instead of it I should use just char[]. Does it concern also function types? I paste below this what I read and my code below.

> will place "Hello world" in the read-only parts of the memory, and making s a pointer to that makes any writing operation on this memory illegal
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

```
char* GetModulePath()
{
    char ownPth[MAX_PATH];

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleFileName(hModule, ownPth, (sizeof(ownPth)));
    }
    return ownPth;
}
```

So is it ok? Maybe instead of char* I should do it using const chars* ? 
EDIT: added link of this article which I've read.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local function variable, this is bad and has nothing to do with `char*` vs `char[]`. `ownPth` no longer exists once you return from `GetModulePath()`.

Comment: `char*` and `char[]` are two different types. Maybe the question would be more clear if you provide a link to the place where read that. If it is about how to store strings, then just use `std::string`

Comment: In C++, you *should* be using `std::string` except for interfacing into C APIs that require character arrays.

Comment: @crashmstr except that `std::string` has a `c_str()` method, so you really never need raw char arrays as strings in c++

Comment: ... and `std::string` has a `c_str()` method for that.

Comment: So should I change type to std::string, return also std::string and in scope of this funcion just convert from char to string?

Comment: @Michał Yes, that sounds like a good option.

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: You are using C++ => use `std::string`

Comment: @Michał Basically to stay out of most trouble, use `std::string` (or if using wide strings, `std::wstring`) for all string work until you're forced to send a pointer to a legacy function.  There is no need to introduce `const char *` or `char *` coding when it is not necessary.

Comment: @user463035818 except for when you need to pass an array of characters that the function will *modify* the contents, sure. There *are* ways of doing this - [C++ - Using STL Strings at Win32 API Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238407.aspx), but they are not always as simple as `.c_str()`

Comment: @crashmstr `string::data()` is non-const since c++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to have a function with a `char*` return type, like that :

```cpp
char* f() {
    char* r = new char[20];
    //Your logic
    return r;
}

int main() {
    char* v = f();
    //More logic
    //Don't forget to delete the dynamically allocated data when you don't need it
    delete[] v;
}
```

However, your code has a problem : you try to return the local variable `ownPth`, and that's a problem.
In the line :

```
return ownPth;
```

you just return the pointer to the first element of the char array, which will be "destroyed" after the function call, and trying to dereference the returned value from outside will result in undefined behavior.

What you should do is using `std::string` like that :

```cpp
std::string GetModulePath()
{
    char ownPth[MAX_PATH] = {0}; // Zero initialization

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleFileName(hModule, ownPth, (sizeof(ownPth)));
    }
    return std::string(ownPth);
}
```

Or, if you really want to use char arrays, you should use heap allocation ( with `new` and `delete` ), but i don't recommand it :

```cpp
char* GetModulePath()
{
    char* ownPth = new char[MAX_PATH];
    memset(ownPth,0,MAX_PATH); //Write zeroes in the allocated memory
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleFileName(hModule, ownPth, MAX_PATH);
        //Not using sizeof, because now, ownPth is not a char array, it's a pointer
    }
    return ownPth; // You will need to delete[] it after, else it's a memory leak
}
```

As said in the comments below, it's very poor practice, and chances are, at some point, you will forget to call `delete[]` just after using it, after a function call, creating a memory leak

Comment: The last option is very, very poor practice. Don't do this ever.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's why i don't recommend that. Chances are that you will forget to `delete[]` somewhere after the call and create memory leak

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun you should know about `std::unique_ptr` then. Manual memory management through `new` is an advanced topic. `std::unique_ptr` achieve the same but is substantially simply. Do yourself a favor and read about it.

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun every time you forget a delete or type a new, you should put it a little upper in your list ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is OK, but in your case you are returning a pointer to a local variable (mentioned in comments).

But anyway in C++ you just do this:

```
std::string GetModulePath()
{
    char ownPth[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleFileName(hModule, ownPth, sizeof(ownPth));
    }

    return std::string(ownPth);
}
```